# programmatically create styles in Android without referring to resources

Tags: android, dynamic, styles, spannablestring

I'm working on an app that reads in text from an XML document and then displays that text on the screen. I want to be able to create a `TextAppearanceSpan` object programmatically based on parameters given in the XML document (font, size, color, bold/italic, etc.) that don't rely on Resource files (for `SpannableString`s in my TextView).

I was looking at the following constructor:

`TextAppearanceSpan(String family, int style, int size, ColorStateList color, ColorStateList linkColor)`

but I can't seem to find any information on how `ColorStateList`s work. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the source code for ColorStateList here:

[GrepCode: ColorStateList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/content/res/ColorStateList.java)

For example, the following XML selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/testcolor1"/>
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/testcolor2" />
   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/testcolor3" />
   <item android:color="@color/testcolor5"/>
 </selector>
```

is equivalent to the following code:

```
int[][] states = new int[4][];
int[] colors = new int[4];

states[0] = new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused };
states[1] = new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed, -android.R.attr.state_enabled };
states[2] = new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_enabled };
states[3] = new int[0];

colors[0] = getResources().getColor(R.color.testcolor1);
colors[1] = getResources().getColor(R.color.testcolor2);
colors[2] = getResources().getColor(R.color.testcolor3);
colors[3] = getResources().getColor(R.color.testcolor5);

ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

The documentation for what a color state and how selectors work is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).